# Why does fetch call with Formdata empty map in testing fetch call using react?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Trying to test a `fetch` call with Formdata in react app with jest.

```js
export const submitform = async (url:string, file:File, params:{}) => {
  const body = new FormData()
  body.append('file', file)

  if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
      body.append(key, params[key])
    })
  }

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${'abc'}`
    },
    body
  })
  return res.json()
}
```

I have a file, that I will be getting in the form and few additional parameters.

Here is the test that I have set up.
`test.js`

```js
  const myParams = { a: 'a', b: 'b' }
  const response = await submitform(postUrl, file, myParams)
  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

  expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    "/url",
    expect.objectContaining({
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${'abc'}`
      },
      body: myParams
    })
  )
```

I get this error In logs:

```js
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: "/url", ObjectContaining {"body": {"a": "a", "b": "b"}, "headers": {"authorization": "Bearer abc"}, "method": "post"}
Received: "/url", {"body": {}, "headers": {"authorization": "Bearer abc"}, "method": "post"}

Number of calls: 1
```

I have tried logging at different steps.
I have received the data in the function and right before the function call.

```js
  console.log('BODY', body)
  console.log('FILE', body.get('file'))
  console.log('A', body.get('a'))
  console.log('B', body.get('b'))
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${'abc'}`
    },
    body
  })
```

The output is like so:

```
    BODY FormData {}
    FILE File {}
    A a
    B b
```

So why does the fetch call with empty body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

`index.ts`:

```
export const submitform = async (url: string, file: File, params: Record<string, any>) => {
  const body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', file);

  if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
    Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
      body.append(key, params[key]);
    });
  }

  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${'abc'}`,
    },
    body,
  });
  return res.json();
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { submitform } from '.';

describe('73309858', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    expect.assertions(3);
    const mResponse = { json: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({}) };
    const mFetch: jest.MockedFunction<typeof fetch> = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mResponse);
    global.fetch = mFetch;
    const myParams = { a: 'a', b: 'b' };
    const postUrl = '/url';
    const file = new File(['a'], 'avatar');
    await submitform(postUrl, file, myParams);
    expect(mFetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mFetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      '/url',
      expect.objectContaining({
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${'abc'}`,
        },
        body: expect.any(FormData),
      })
    );
    const callArgs = mFetch.mock.calls[0][1];
    if (callArgs) {
      const body = callArgs.body as FormData;
      const formData = Array.from(body.entries()).reduce(
        (acc, f) => ({ ...acc, [f[0]]: f[1] }),
        {} as Record<string, any>
      );
      expect(formData).toMatchObject(myParams);
    }
  });
});
```

package version:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```